# Versae's Neo4j python rest client and graph algos access

Tags: rest, neo4j, graph-algorithm

I'm using [versae's neo4j rest client](https://github.com/versae/neo4j-rest-client) to access a neo4j DB but I stumbled upon a problem trying to figure out how to use the paths algorithms from a node.

In the neo4j documentation it says that there are built-in graph algos in the URL *db/data/node/NODE_ID/paths* but it seems like versae's API doesn't allow access to these algos, as I read in the docs it has access to "extensions" but not to the default built-in algos.

Anyone knows how to access these methods without having to create a server extension just to reimplement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

piva,

Currently there's no way to access to algos factory from the [neo4jrestclient](https://github.com/versae/neo4j-rest-client). But I think it's the time to implement this. I hope to release a new version with this feature before the end of the next week.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks versae, I'd asked that in your github project too but as I was not allowed to answer my question that day I forgot to add your comment from the issue to this page :)

Comment: I forgot to mention here that the GraphAlgo, likely, is going to be removed from in favor of Cypher queries, and they are already implemented.

Comment: Here the [link](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-graph-algos.html#comment-409915290).

Comment: Wow, thanks for the update, I'm no longer in the company that was using Neo4j but it's nice to know that :)